# Pytorch: How do I deal with different input sizes within one batch?

Tags: deep-learning, set, pytorch

I am implementing something closely related to the DeepSets architecture on point clouds:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.06114

That means I am working with a set of inputs (coordinates), have fully connected layers process each of those seperately and then perform average pooling over them (to then do further processing).

The input for each sample **i** is a tensor of shape `[L_i, 3]` where `L_i` is the number of points and the last dimension is `3` because each points has x,y,z coordinates. Crucially, `L_i` depends on the sample. So I have a different number of points per instance. When I put everything into a batch, I currently have the input in the shape `[B, L, 3]` where `L` is larger than `L_i` for all i. The individual samples are padded with 0's. The issue is that 0's are not ignored by the network, they are processed and fed into the average pooling. Instead I would like the average pooling to only consider actual points (not padded 0's). I do have another array which stores the lengths `[L_1, L_2, L_3, L_4...]`, but I am not sure how to use it.

My Question is: How do you handle different input sizes wihtin one batch in the most graceful manner?

This is how the model is define:

```
encoder = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(3, 128), nn.ReLU(), nn.Linear(128, 128))
x = self.encoder(x)
x = x.max(dim=1)[0]
decoder = ...
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something but in your example code where are you performing average pooling?

Comment: I am doing max-pooling in this version (`x.max(dim=1)[0]`). My goal is to stay flexible regarding which pooling type or even more complex operations. Hence, the solution shouldn't include adding a mean to the zero values etc.